# git how to backup in zip for Untracked files

Tags: git

git need to take a backup in zip for Untracked files

I need to take a back up in zip in git for Untracked files  for all files need to take

```
$ git status --short

M .gitignore

?? file 1

?? File 2

....
```

I need to take a backup

Working on python windows

Comment: get a `git status --short` and only get the files that have `??` as their status.... then you can create the zip (_not_ using `git`, for sure) using only those files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Will Help

```
git status --short | cut -c4- > unstaged_files.txt
tar -czvf unstaged_backup.tar.gz -T unstaged_files.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get list of unstaged files with `git status [--short]` and zip them. oneliner to do this:

```
## change to root of your git repository
cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"

## zip unstaged files into /tmp/rr.zip
zip -r /tmp/rr.zip  $(git status --short | awk '$1 = "??" { print $NF} ')
```